# Segue using didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a Master-Detail VC setup for a Core Data project. If the `searchBar` is active, one set of results is displayed, if it's not active, the objects from the fetchedResultsController displays in the MasterVC.

I had been trying to segue using `prepareForSegue`, but I my instructor suggested I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to do the segue.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedNote: Note

    // Check to see which table view cell was selected.
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        selectedNote = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Note // <--this is "everything"
    } else {
        // need this to unwrap the optional
        if let filteredObjects = filteredObjects {
            selectedNote = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    // Set up the detail view controller to show.
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
    detailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel = selectedNote.valueForKey("noteBody") as! UILabel

    // Note: Should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug requires it.
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: false)

    // original code
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)

}
```

I'm getting this compiler error:

`Variable 'selectedNote' used before being initialized`--it's declared at the top of the method!

If I add `"self"` before `selectedNote` like so:

```
    detailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel = self.selectedNote.valueForKey("noteBody") as! UILabel
```

`'MasterViewController' does not have a member named 'selectedNote'` despite being there. So I'm obviously mucking up something.

I put a breakpoint in before `let detailViewController = DetailViewController()` and in `lldb` it's printing out the right object. I've looked around here for a solution, but I'm coming up short. I can't find applicable code that works on GitHub.

```
class Note: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dateCreated: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateEdited: NSDate
    @NSManaged var noteTitle: String
    @NSManaged var noteBody: String

}
```

Any ideas how to pass the `selectedNote`'s properties forward to the `detailViewController`?

**Update:**

Based on the responses I've gotten, I've shut up the compiler warnings with this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedNote: Note?

    // Check to see which table view cell was selected.
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        selectedNote = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Note // <--this is "everything"
    } else {
        // need this to unwrap the optional
        if let filteredObjects = filteredObjects {
            selectedNote = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    // Set up the detail view controller to show.
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()

    detailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel.text = (selectedNote!.valueForKey("noteBody") as! String)

    // Note: Should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug requires it.
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: false)

    // original code
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)

}
```

But I'm getting this in the console when it crashes:
`There are already notes in the app
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

However, when I type `po selectedObject` the object I clicked displays in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare **selectedNote** as optional like this:

```
  var selectedNote: Note?
```

And later check if value exist before using it.

```
  if let note = selectedNote {
    // Set up the detail view controller to show.
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
    detailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel = note.valueForKey("noteBody") as! UILabel

    // Note: Should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug requires it.
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: false)            
    // original code
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
  }
```

**Update**:

The problem is that you are trying to create DetailViewController

```
let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
```

But what you need instead is to have reference to the DetailViewController in order to pass information to it.

So you can create segue from Master to Detail controller in Interface builder. Then remove logic from **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Note: Should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug requires it.
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: false)
}
```

And implement it in **prepareForSegue** method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {

            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!

            var selectedNote: Note?

            if filteredObjects?.count > 0 {
                selectedNote = filteredObjects![indexPath.row]
            }else {
                selectedNote = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Note // <--this is "everything"
            }

            if let note = selectedNote {

                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = note
            }
        }
    }
}
```

showDetail - segue identifier which you need to setup in IB. 
var detailItem: AnyObject?  - you need to declare it in DetailViewController.

Comment: That's a little progress. Now I get this: `There are already notes in the app
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10f759c90) to 'UILabel' (0x110b1b968).` I did `po selectedNote` on `lldb` and it returns the note I selected, but it crashed

Comment: While this technically removes the compiler error, there is a chance selectedNote does not get initialized, leading to a crash when selectedNote is used. You are best off to use a regular optional... var selectedNote: Note?

Comment: Adrian, take a look at this code: selectedNote.valueForKey("noteBody") as! UILabel. Are you sure that selectedNote contains UILabel? I guess it contain text that you want to put in detailDescriptionLabel. In such case you need to cast to NSString instead of UILabel?

Comment: Here's the property from the `DetailVC`: `@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!`

Comment: I don't know internals of Note class but I guess what you want to write is as follow: detailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel.text = note.valueForKey("noteBody") as! NSString.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not there yet, but I've shut the compiler up. Here's the project GitHub (Xcode 6.3 beta). https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/blocnotes/tree/add-pull-down-search-bar-take-6

Comment: Thank you, @RomanSalabay. I have 2 sets of results I'm trying to account for. One set is displayed if the searchBar is active, which would be the `filteredResults` index. The other is if the `searchBar` is inactive, which would return the `tableView` index. I think you've almost gotten me there in terms of fixing it. I've got a week in this.

Comment: @RomanSalabay I've almost got it figured out, thanks to you. I think my problem lurks on the `DetailVC` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801266/segue-not-setting-value-to-detail-view-controller