# Segue not setting value to detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a Master-Detail VC set up and I've figured out how to set up a segue to my Detail VC. The code below doesn't crash, but it also doesn't send a value for the label to the VC I'm pushing to.

I'm stumped as to how I pass the value of `detailViewController.detailItem = selectedNote?.noteBody` to my `DetailViewController`.

The code below compiles. It does not crash. But it also doesn't set anything on my `DetailViewController`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // This is my object
    var selectedNote: Note?

    /*
    I do NOT want to use prepareForSegue. I have 2 diff't sets of notes I'm dealing with. One in 
    the managedObjectContext and the other is in filteredObjects array.
    */

    // This gets selectedNote from the fetchedResultsController
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        selectedNote = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Note // <--this is "everything"
    } else {
        // This get a note from the filteredObjects array
        // This statement is necessary to unwrap the optional
        if let filteredObjects = filteredObjects {
            selectedNote = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    // Set up the detail view controller to show.
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()

    // This is nil. I want to to set a value on the detailVC before I segue
    self.detailViewController!.detailItem = selectedNote?.noteBody

    // Note: Should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug requires it.
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: false)

    // this does the segue.
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)

}
```

I'm missing something very easy here, but I can't figure it out. Here is my `DetailViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    var note: Note?

    var detailItem: AnyObject? = nil {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }
    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = self.detailItem as? Note {
            note = detail
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.noteBody
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()
    }
```

Here's my `Note` class:

```
class Note: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dateCreated: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateEdited: NSDate
    @NSManaged var noteTitle: String
    @NSManaged var noteBody: String

}
```

Comment: If you're programmatically creating a `DetailViewController`, I don't think Xcode generates any automatic construction code for the detailDescriptionLabel hence it would start off as `nil`. Have you tried creating a debug-only `init` to check that? I'm not an expert on this so I can't put this as answer.

Comment: Thank you. I set a breakpoint before the segue and the value is "there", but it's not getting passed. I think I'm screwing something up on the `DetailVC` side.

Comment: How far through the `if let` chain does execution get in `configureView`? I may be missing something easy as well, but I don't see where `self.detailItem` ever becomes non-nil.

Comment: On the `MasterVC` it gets to `detailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel.text = detailDescriptionLabel`, where it crashes. There's a value there, but I don't think it's getting set in the `DetailVC`.

Comment: Then my first comment looks to be correct. If so I'll promote it to answer. Try changing the `@IBOutlet` line to just: `var detailDescriptionLabel = UILabel()` but even after that, unless there's code you're not sharing, `detailItem` remains `nil` throughout.

Comment: In `configureView`, there's now a compiler error on the `if let label = self.detailLabelDescription` line: `Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type`

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to create new DocumentViewController. But because you are using storyboard you don't need to do it manually. All you need to do is to get reference to the already created DetailViewController. In your case the best place to get reference to the view controller and pass data to it is "prepareForSegue" method.

Comment: I believe you're working in two conflicting strategies: A) Creating the transition programmatically, where you're responsible for calling `init` or `initWithNibName` properly and B) Using Xcode and designing the navigation visually with a genuine Segue. For starting out, B) is better to start and there's a "Push" segue example in this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2